# Remove last word in bash variable

Tags: bash

I have something like that:

```
...
args=$*
echo $args
...
```

result is

```
unusable1 unusable2 useful useful ... useful unusable3
```

I need remove all "unusable" args. They always at first, second and last position. 
After some investigation i find `${*:3}` bash syntax. It help remove first two.

```
...
args=${*:3}
echo $args
...
```

result is

```
useful useful ... useful unusable3
```

But I can't find how to remove last word using same nice syntax.

Comment: `args=$*`, by the way, is flattening your list into a string. You probably don't want to do that -- think about when your argument list is `./hello world "some file name with spaces"`; that'll make `args=hello world some file name with spaces`.

Comment: ...the Right Thing is an array: `args=( "$@" )`; you can then refer to all-but-the-last as `"${args[@]:1:$#-1}"` without losing boundary data (until/unless you assign that array to a string, at which point all your care to keep things right is out the window -- so don't ever do that!)

Comment: Anyhow, if you gave us information on how you're actually *using* that variable, we'd have more basis to give an answer that incorporates whether the right way to store it is an array or a string.

Comment: I try to write completion script. Sometimes (in my case) incomplete word (which we enter now) can broke my script. So It's necessary to remove it (last word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args=${*:3}` flattens your argument list. You don't want to do that. Consider following the pattern given below instead:

```
# this next line sets "$@" for testing purposes; you don't need it in real life
set -- \
  "first argument" \
  "second argument" \
  "third argument" \
  "fourth argument" \
  "fifth argument"

# trim the first two
args=( "${@:2}" )

# trim the last one
args=( "${args[@]:1:$(( ${#args[@]} - 2 ))}" )

# demonstrate the output content
printf '<%s>\n' "${args[@]}"
```

Running the above yields the following output:

```
<third argument>
<fourth argument>
```

...and, by doing so, demonstrates that it's correctly keeping arguments together, even when they contain spaces or wildcard characters.

---

For a shell completion script, you might also consider:

```
printf '%q ' "${args[@]}"
```

...which quotes content in such a way as to be eval'able by the shell.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a function/script like this to print all but last arguments:

```
func() {
   echo "${@:1:$#-1}";
}

func aa bb cc dd ee
aa bb cc dd

func foo bar baz hello how are you
foo bar baz hello how are
```

Answer (score 3):

Using your syntax, you can use this :

```
args=${*:3:$#-3}
```

Explanation :

```
${*:offset:length}
```

offset is 3 to begin to the third argument and length is the number of arguments minus 3 (two first and last one).

Comment: -1: The use of `$*` instead of `$@` is incorrect when dealing with an argument list unless one explicitly wants to treat `./prog "arg one" "arg two"` the same as `./prog arg one arg two`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it doesn't fit with arguments with a space. But he already used it in his question.

Comment: indeed, and that means he's writing software with bugs. Better to show the right way to do things, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
args="unusable1 unusable2 useful useful ... useful unusable3"
args=$(awk '{$1=$2=$NF="";print}' <<< "$args")
echo "$args"
```

Output:

```
  useful useful ... useful
```

The command sets the the first, second and the last (`$NF`) position to an empty string. `NF` holds the number of fields in awk. Therefore `$NF` is the last column.

Comment: Nice solution. If I understand right $NF responsible for the last word, and there is no way get penultimate word.

Comment: @StepanLoginov The penultimate field can be accessed using `$(NF-1)`

Comment: The concern here is that it isn't respecting word boundaries the way the shell parsed them, but is recombining shell-parsed words (with the first character of IFS), and feeding them back in for parsing by awk. This makes it a lot harder to get things right if your arguments could have spaces, or if your IFS doesn't match up with awk's word-separation behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, your concerns are valid, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` doesn't really provide such filtering methods for arrays. The best option is to just use a loop and filter one at a time.

```
for arg; do   # Implicitly iterate over $@
    [[ $arg =~ unusable ]] && continue
    args+=( "$arg" )
done
```

Comment: I guess, you missed this line in the question.. `They always at first, second and last position.` :-)

Comment: Yeah, I kind of skimmed over that and focused on the "unusable" tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
args=$*

useful=${args#* }
useful=${useful#* }
useful=${useful% *}
```

Then you wlill get the interesting parameters in the `$result` variable.

Comment: -1: Treating argument lists as if they were strings.